# Buttons with more than one action?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, button, interface-builder

I have a button that I need to both delete something, and close a sheet. Being that there is only one 'Sent Actions' connection, how do I connect it to two actions?

Zach

Comment: +1 good question, especially coming from UIKit, where this *is* possible.

Comment: You may want to consider filing an enhancement request radar with Apple.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot do this with AppKit.  What you can do is hook it up to a single action, and then have that action invoke other methods.

Comment: By "action" Dave means "instance method".

Comment: By "action" Dave means "action method" (as opposed to an arbitrary instance method) as described in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html ;-)

Comment: By "action", I meant the term that @Zakman411 was using in his question, which happens to match @Bavarious' definition. :)  The difference being that an action is an instance method, but not all instance methods are (or can be) actions.

Comment: Does anyone have a dummies version of all of this? I don't see how to do that in IB, there's only one connection allowed for Sent Actions.

Comment: …which you want to connect to a single IBAction that implements both "deleting something and closing a sheet".